# CMake build error: undefined reference to 'deflateEnd'

Tags: c++, cmake, zlib, conan

I'm trying to use zlib in my project. The CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(cmake-demo LANGUAGES CXX)
# The version number.
set(CMDemo_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(CMDemo_VERSION_MINOR 1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/conan_paths.cmake)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
find_package(uwebsockets)

#ZLIB
if(ZLIB_FOUND)
  set(INC_DIRS ${INC_DIRS} ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(LINK_LIBS ${LINK_LIBS} ${ZLIB_LIBS})
endif()

# Global approach
if(uwebsockets_FOUND)
  set(INC_DIRS ${INC_DIRS} ${uwebsockets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(LINK_LIBS ${LINK_LIBS} ${uwebsockets_LIBS})
endif()

#libuv
if(libuv_FOUND)
  set(INC_DIRS ${INC_DIRS} ${libuv_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(LINK_LIBS ${LINK_LIBS} ${libuv_LIBS})
endif()

#usockets
if(usockets_FOUND)
  set(INC_DIRS ${INC_DIRS} ${usockets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(LINK_LIBS ${LINK_LIBS} ${usockets_LIBS})
endif()

include_directories(${INC_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
message("libs=${LINK_LIBS}")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LINK_LIBS})
```

```
#output of message("${LINK_LIBS}")
C:/ProgramData/Miniconda3/Library/lib/z.lib;C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/libuv/1.41.0/_/_/package/9965605309592d7e617ec929633249a2031e4263/lib/libuv_a.a;C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/a24f5291464b4270092bce2e738cbf9f3cd53bb7/lib/libuSockets.a
```

I'm sure that ${LINK_LIBS} is correct, but it still doesn't work:

```
CMakeFiles/cmake-demo.dir/main.cpp.obj: In function `ZN3uWS15DeflationStreamD1Ev':
C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/uwebsockets/19.2.0/_/_/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/include/uWebSockets/PerMessageDeflate.h:186: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
```

os: Windows10 x64

IDE: QtCreator4.14.2

compiler: MinGW 32-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, that you have to set the path to the library file as the `target_link_libraries` argument.

According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html), if you want to link the library, each argument of `target_link_libraries` can be:

- A library target name
- A full path to a library file (e.g. `/usr/lib/foo.so`)
- A plain library name (e.g. `foo`)

In your case I suggest you to add the complete path to the library.

I don't have all the code of your project, so I suggest you consider this minimal example:

```
add_executable(test main.cpp)

SET (ZLIB_ROOT "/tmp/zlib")
SET (ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR "/tmp/zlib/include/")
SET (ZLIB_LIBRARY "/tmp/zlib/lib/libz.so.1.2.11")

FIND_PACKAGE (ZLIB REQUIRED)
MESSAGE (" zlib version major is " ${ZLIB_VERSION_MAJOR})
MESSAGE (" zlib version minor is " ${ZLIB_VERSION_MINOR})
MESSAGE (" zlib include is " ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
MESSAGE (" zlib libraries are " ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(test ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

After downloading the [latest zlib release](https://zlib.net/) and installing it in `/tmp`, everything works as expected.

---

**Update**: as [@uilianries](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2036859/uilianries) mentioned, since you are using conan, you have [cmake_find_package](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake_find_package.html) generator that defines variables with all the necessary paths. So you don't need to set the paths in `CMakeLists.txt` manually.

Comment: Almost correct. As SinoDawn is using Conan, it requires [cmake_find_package](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake_find_package.html) genarator too. So, don't need to set ZLIB_ROOT and so on.

Comment: Yes, the var is generated by conan. Actually, I'm using uwebsockets which depends on zlib. The full CMakeLists is as follow. I have tried different way to link the zlib but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the libzlib.a is for x86_64 while the compiler is MinGW-32bit; I solved the problem by execute the command

```
$conan install .. --build=missing --pr=x86_32
```

the x86_64 is a profile(x86) generated by conan.